# Check whether or not Simple injector has registered type

Tags: c#, simple-injector

How can I archive automatic registration but ignore any types have already been registered? I reference the code in Simple Injector documentation

```
var repositoryAssembly = typeof(SqlUserRepository).Assembly;

var registrations =
    from type in repositoryAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where type.Namespace == "MyComp.MyProd.BL.SqlRepositories"
    where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
    select new 
    { 
        Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), 
        Implementation = type 
    };

foreach (var reg in registrations) 
{
    // TODO: how to check reg.Service has already registered or not
    container.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Transient);
}
```

For example, I have inteface ISampleRepository and there are 2 implementations in different assemblies

1. SampleRepository is in assembly "MyComp.MyProd.BL.SqlRepositories"
2. OverrideSampleRepository is in different one

Project 1: worked

```
var container = new Container();
container.AutoRegistration();
```

Project 2: exception because ISampleRepository has already registered

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<ISampleRepository, OverrideSampleRepository>();
container.AutoRegistration();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation [described](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations) how to override existing registrations. The documentation contains the following example:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

// Register IUserService.
container.Register<IUserService, FakeUserService>();

// Replaces the previous registration
container.Register<IUserService, RealUserService>();
```

Do however read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to check for registration by doing this

```
container.Verify();
container.GetRegistration(reg.Service) != null; // Not registered
```

Comment: container.GetRegistration(reg.Service) called before veryfying so it does not work. Exception: the container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance, GetAllInstances and Verify